# one hour gnss (gps, etc) rms

Tags: python, pandas, gps

Typically with Global Navigation Satellite System (gnss) observations; accuracy metrics are through root mean square and their variations. Two explanations [here](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Positioning_Error) and [here](https://gnss-sdr.org/design-forces/accuracy/).
This is possible when the error distribution is Gaussian. i.e.: [with many observations; generally 24 hours - one per second](https://www.gpsworld.com/gps-accuracy-lies-damn-lies-and-statistics/).

I have one hour gnss observations and their distribution is not Gaussian. Are more observations necessary? I mean: given the nature of the gnss is an rms possible with one hour of observations? Would a moving rms be applicable here?

From [Difference between RMS and a moving RMS](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42059/difference-between-rms-and-a-moving-rms)  I understand there are two possible solutions:

continuous time:

[image]

and discrete time:

[image]

With the *continuous time* variant: Is an rms for every epoch possible?
How would I go about implementing this in a [pandas df](https://github.com/AdrianKriger/realTimePPP101/blob/main/static/sol/cpt_202110240757.csv) *~ with python*?
where: `deltay`, `deltax` and `deltaz` are *observation* minus *known*, for each co-ordinate dimension, at every epoch. The frequency of the signals range from 1176.45 to 1575.42 MHz.

Comment: I'm not sure you are in the right forum: your question is very specialized. I think the site galmon.eu should have done a similar job (they get raw GPS data and analyze the different parameters). PS: I do not think it is Gaussian on short term: atmosphere is not changing so fast, so you should have skewed results. Depending on your location, Multipath may arise only on some satellite elevation, so skew only on one direction and on some psecific cases. Also you will get the same satellites.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask at [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) and [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) StackExchange.